# Visa requirements for spouse of UK citizen

Tags: visas, south-african-citizens, spouses

I am a UK citizen, living in South Africa with my South African husband. I can travel to the UK with my UK passport, but my husband always has to apply for a visitor's visa, and pay for it. Is there some way we can get around this and possibly not pay the visa application fee?

Comment: I feel your pain, as I am the South African in the same situation you have, and user16259's answer is correct. Since we only travel to the UK at most once per year I just have to suck it up and pay the visa fee every time.The way the long-term visas are priced doesn't make sense for less than 2 or 3 trips per year unless you just want to avoid the hassle.

Answer (score 4):

Your husband is a visa national and so by definition needs a visa. Your least troublesome option is a longer duration visit visa. This would allow him to make multiple visits over several years on a single visa. The fee is higher than a short duration visa so the value of it depends on your travel habits.